# Cannot cast List`1[MyClass]' to type List`1[MyClass_Accessor]'?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I got the following error when running the test code. How to workaround the issue? I'm using Visual studio 2010 Premium's built-in MStest.

```
Test method TestProgram.myProgramTest.GetTypeListTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProgram.MyClass]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProgram.MyClass_Accessor]'.
```

Method to be tested:

```
public class MyProjectClass {
    private List<MyClass> GetTypeList()
    { .... 
    }
}

class MyClass {....} // A POCO class
```

Test code (Most of the code is automatically generated by Visual studio):

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("myProgram.exe")]
public void GetTypeListTest()
{
    MyProjFile_Accessor target = new MyProjFile_Accessor ();
    var actual = target.GetTypeList();
    Assert.IsTrue(actual.Count > 2);
}
```

**I really don't know why this question has been down voted twice, all other code is either irrelevant to the issue or automatically generated by Visual studio**
It's pretty straight forward class definition. And the test fixture was created using VS 2010 wizard. The method just return `MyClass` can pass the test. The problem is the method with return type of `List<MyClass>`.

Comment: Does MyClass_Accessor inherit from MyClass? Currently you're trying to take a list of apples and cast it as a list of oranges. Even if MyClass_Accessor : MyClass, you can't cast to a list (as it has read/write properties) Look at C# 4's `in` and `out` keywords for more info on casting, co- and contra-variance

Comment: Does your code ever cast to `List<MyProgram.MyClass_Accessor>`? That cast isn't possible, don't support generic variance.

Comment: Looks like you need to review and maybe fix the (generated?) accessor. Did you change interfaces _after_ generating the first test-cases?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I deleted and regenerated the test case and it still raises the exception.

Comment: @James I was surprised to see the code too. However, the test code is generated by Visual Studio 2010 Wizard (MSTest). I didn't write the code myself. This is the first time I have problem with the generated test code.

Comment: We need to know more about the MyProjFile_Accessor class. I am unfamiliar with mstest, is it generating thos *_Accessor classes? If so, the problem lies in how MSTest is creating these objects. It might be enforcing inheritance, but having trouble with generic collection. What version of C# are you using?

Comment: Try changing `List<MyClass>` to IEnumerable<MyClass>. C# 4.0 will allow a cast from `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` to `IEnumerable<DerivedClass>` as the scope is finer. Alternatively, if you test the class directly, and not the autogenerated _Accessor class, just replace `MyProjFile_Accessor` with `MyProjectClass `

Comment: But did you also delete and regen the Accessor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `MyClass` has no access modifier and C# uses `internal` access modifier by default.

Internal means that class is accessible only inside its assembly.

Unit tests usually implemented in separate assembly and cannot use `MyClass`.

MS Tests generated `MyClass_Accessor` class that is essentially a wrapper that uses reflection to provide access to class itself as well as its methods.

Change declaration to `public class MyClass {....}` and re-generate unit test (this is necessary to tell MS Test that `_Accessor` class is not necessary).